# The fundamental group of the connected sum of two copies of the real projective plane

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

How do I compute the fundamental group of the connected sum $X \mathop{\#} X$, where $X$ denotes the real projective plane?

I'd like to use Van Kampen's theorem, but I have trouble visualizing what this space looks like. Could anyone provide hints?

Comment: The decomposition you want to use van Kampen on comes straight out of the definition.

Answer (score 3):

The real projective plane $\mathbb{RP}^2$ can be represented as the following identification bi-gon:

[image: The fundamental polygon of the real projective plane]

By taking two of these bigons, cutting each at a vertex, and gluing them together again, we obtain the identification polygon for $\mathbb{RP}^2 \# \mathbb{RP}^2$:<sup>*</sup>

[image: The fundamental polygon of the connected sum of two real projective planes]

Now, let $P$ be an interior point of the identification polygon.  Then, we can apply the Seifert-van Kampen Theorem to $\mathbb{RP}^2 \# \mathbb{RP}^2 = \mathbb{RP}^2 \# \mathbb{RP}^2 \setminus \{P\} \cup D$, where $D$ is a small disk containing $P$.  <sup>**</sup>

Can you take it from here?

---

<sup>*</sup> : Note that $\mathbb{RP}^2 \# \mathbb{RP}^2$ is in fact homeomorphic to the Klein bottle.  This can be seen by cutting and regluing the identification polygon.

<sup>**</sup> : This is a standard trick for finding fundamental groups of compact surfaces.  We first realize the surface as an identification polygon, and then apply the Seifert-van Kampen Theorem to the polygon with a point $P$.removed and a small disk around $P$.